# JSON not readable in POST method

Tags: json, angularjs, node.js

I'm trying to send data from a front-end application (Angular) to a node server. I created a form to allow the application to send data through a POST method, and so I did this:

```
$http.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';       
var res = $http.post('http://myserver/saveMessage', JSON.stringify($scope.formData));
res.success(function(data) {
    console.log('data sent')    
});
res.error(function(data) {
   console.log('Error: ' + data);
});
```

My node server looks like this:

```
router.post('/saveMessage', function(req, res) {    
    console.log(req.body);  
});
```

Everything seems to be working well, but when I send data, it looks like this in the browser console:

```
Object {"Nom" : "toto", "Message":"test"}
```

And it looks like this once received by the node:

```
{ '{"Nom":"toto","Message":"test"}': '' }
```

I'm using nginx to serve the server application (because it's running on, for example, port 3000) and I'm using 'grunt serve' to serve the client application (so it's running on another port, for example, 3001).

Do you have any idea why my JSON is received like this and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have set the content type to `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`, and you're stringifying JSON, yet you're expecting to receive a JSON object on your server.

If you want to send JSON to your server, a) you don't need to set the content type header (`$http` will intelligently guess this, as long as you don't have default headers set), and b) just put it in the body of `$http.post` as a plain JavaScript object, and the service will take care of it for you.

If for some reasons you need a different default header, then you can do a one-off header for the request that sends JSON by setting it to `application/json`.

Comment: Hi Josh thank you for your answer.
I removed the stringify and the header but my node server receive now the 'post' method as 'option' method so I can't retreive my data with req.body.
How can I get my data from req?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but it seems dirty.

Finaly I use $http with get method and send my data by stringifing my object. I parse it on node side.

Do you think my system is enough protected if I use credentials with this method?